# Delphi Form Drag Lockup

Tags: delphi, firefox, forms, mouse, drag

Make a Delphi 2007 application, TForm as main window.
Run application.  Try to drag the form using the caption bar.  The debugger shows an unending stream of error messages, complaining it can't find some unnamed routine.  Escape and Break don't work.  3 finger salute doesn't work.
Clicking in some other window and then back to the Delphi application stops the avalanche of error messages and allows the application to function in its original location (the form itself hasn't moved).

Strangely, on occasion I've had related behavior using Firefox -- clicking in the browser window doesn't work 'til I click in some non-Firefox window, after which the browser window is active again.

Anyone seen related behavior?  Suggestions?  Might it be a mouse driver problem?  Toshiba laptop with ALPS touchpad mouse.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound related to Delphi specifically.  The "stream of error messages, complaining it can't find some unnamed routine" sounds very odd.  Could you post one or two of the actual messages, please?

In the meanwhile, my guess is some form of hook or injected code.  Try looking for programs that do that kind of thing and disable them one by one:

- Mouse drivers (as a poster above
  said)
- Antivirus, especially the "big ones"
  like Norton etc
- Some display driver "enhancement"
  utilities
- If you have two screens and you're
  running a second taskbar program, try
  that

and so forth.

It's probably worth doing a virus scan too, you never know :)

Comment: I found a mouse driver version that was a few days newer than the one that I've been using.  I loaded it; it is unclear if it fixed the problem, but I have gone 5 days without a lockup.  Knock on wood, maybe that was it.

Answer (score 0):

I know there was a Logitech driver hook problem when starting a Delphi project in Delphi: it gave an exception on the first line of the .dpr. Outside Delphi it worked OK.

So do you get those exceptions/problems only in Delphi? What kind of error/exceptions?

Comment: It loads, then unloads, an Unknown_Module_10015 at address $01670000.  Not informative ... .  Outside Delphi, at random, Firefox tabs fail to sense mouse clicks unless there's a click in another application after the tab is opened (or becomes top tab).  I recently upgraded some Adobe applications and haven't had that lockup since.  I don't get that either.

Comment: So you don't have that problem anymore?

Anyway, the loading and unloading of the unknown module caused the problem? Because you can see that kind of debug message all the time (windows dll's loading other dll's etc).